# Messaging platform with public-private key pairs as identifier

Tags: cryptography, whisper

Is there any platform available for Ethereum address 0x1d53.. to message 0xcc23..., and so on? It seems like there would be a lot of demand for something like that, which suggests it exists. Off-chain, I guess. I need it for the pairs in Pseudonym Pairs ([source code](https://github.com/0xAnonymous/Polytopia/blob/main/Polytopia.sol)) to agree on a random video channel over something like https://gotalk.to or https://meet.jit.si.

Comment: worst case scenario I'll do it on-chain initially but, doesn't need majority consensus so would be better to have some sort of email-like platform, where messages are stored entirely public for anyone to download, but, only those with the private key could decrypt them. kind of seems like that would already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Ethmail.cc is ordinary email + secp256k1 public-private key accounts, email format `[ETH address]@ethmail.cc`. Then there is BitMessage, closer to what I was thinking of, stores encrypted messages publicly but only owner of private key can decrypt a message, https://bitmessage.org/bitmessage.pdf. Ethmessenger.co was built after 6 months of research by Ethereum Foundation Advisors. Status.im almost supports key-to-key messages, the account is controlled by Ethereum accounts, but adds a different identifier than the public key. dChat supports ENS domain names, and is like Status.im controlled by Ethereum accounts, but, does not support key-to-key messaging.